# Как явно определить какой запрос делать в urls as_view?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Как явно определить какой запрос делать в urls as_view? Просто в swagger они дублируются, что не хорошо по сути

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('addItem/<int:product_id>/', views.InteractionWithCart.as_view()),
    path('getCartInfo/', views.InteractionWithCart.as_view()),
]
```

views.py

```
class InteractionWithCart(APIView):

def get(self, request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    data = cart.get_cart()
    return Response(data)

def post(self, request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    cart.add(product)
    return Response({"status": "add"})
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам проще разделить класс на отдельные функции и работать с ними.

Файл **views.py**

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
# Остальные импорты – Cart, get_object_or_404, Product
    

@api_view(http_method_names=['GET'])
def get_cart_info(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    data = cart.get_cart()
    return Response(data)

@api_view(http_method_names=['POST'])
def add_item_to_cart(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    cart.add(product)
    return Response({"status": "add"})
```

Файл **urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('addItem/<int:product_id>/', views.add_item_to_cart),
    path('getCartInfo/', views.get_cart_info),
]
```